# Peewee doesn't set last insert id

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I use mysql database. Peewee doesn't set `id` field after `save()`

Peewee Model :

```
class OAuthAccount(BaseModel):
    id = BigIntegerField(primary_key=True,index=True,unique=True , db_column="id")
    oauth_provider_id = IntegerField(null=False)
    oauth_uid = CharField()
    oauth_token = CharField()
    oauth_token_secret = CharField()
    username = CharField()
    inserter = BigIntegerField(null=True,db_column="inserter_id")
    insert_date = DateTimeField(null=True,default=fn.NOW())
    updater = BigIntegerField(null=True,db_column="updater_id")
    update_date = DateTimeField(null=True)
    extra_data = CharField()
```

The saving code :

```
oauthUser = OAuthAccount(
                    oauth_provider_id= formData.get("oauth_provider_id"),
                    oauth_uid = formData.get("oauth_uid"),
                    oauth_token = formData.get("oauth_token"),
                    oauth_token_secret=formData.get("oauth_token_secret"),
                    username = formData.get("username"),
                    inserter_id = g.auth.userId(),
                    extra_data = formData.get("extra_data")
                )
oauthUser.save()
print "id => " + str(oauthUser.id)
```

The output is : `id => None`

The row successfully inserted to database. But `id` is still `None`

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand but it worked when i did this changes:

```
id = BigIntegerField(primary_key=True,index=True,unique=True , db_column="id")        
->
id = BigIntegerField( db_column="id")
```

It alse worked with this changes:

```
id = BigIntegerField(primary_key=True,index=True,unique=True , db_column="id")
->
id = PrimaryKeyField( db_column="id")
```

When I put `primary_key=True` it doesn't work.

```
id = BigIntegerField(primary_key=True , db_column="id")
```

Maybe it is a bug?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a bug, per-se, but only the `PrimaryKeyField` or a field with a sequence defined is considered to be auto-incrementing.

With a bit of code, you could add a custom field type for BigInt primary key field, though.

Comment: You mean if I make this change `"id = IntegerField(primary_key=True,index=True,unique=True , db_column="id")"` it will work? Is it because of using BigIntegerField?

Comment: id = PrimaryKeyField() no need to specify index or unique

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
class OAuthAccount(BaseModel):
    id = BigIntegerField(primary_key=True,index=True,unique=True , db_column="id")
```

Try:

```
class OAuthAccount(BaseModel):
    id = PrimaryKeyField()
```

Then the `id` field will be set on your model after `save` and `create`.

If you need to use a bigint you'll need to subclass `PrimaryKeyField`.

Comment: This answer worked for me. I originally had `IntegerField(primary_key=True)`